# org.json.jsonexception value of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: android, json, exception

I ma try to retrieve some data from a mysql database to may android app.
Here is my php code:

```
<?php
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "";
  $players = array();



  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect to the database!");

  $db = mysql_select_db('arsenal') or die("Could not select DB!");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Player");

  $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    //array_push($data, $row["playerName"]);
    $players[] = $row['playerName']."  ".$row['surName']."          ";
    echo $players[$i];
    $i++;
    }
  print(json_encode($players));

  mysql_close($conn);  
?>
```

This is my get data method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getPlayers(){
        ArrayList<String> retRanks = new ArrayList<String>();
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/playerData.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch(Exception exc){
            retRanks.add("Error in http connection " + exc.toString());
            return retRanks;
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception exc){
            retRanks.add("Error converting result " + exc.toString());
            return retRanks;
        }

        //parse json data
        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                retRanks.add(jArray.get(i).toString());

            }
            return retRanks;
        } catch(JSONException exc){
            retRanks.add("Error parsing data " + exc.toString());
            return retRanks;
        }
    }
```

I get this exception :

```
org.json.jsonexception value of type java.lang.string Santi cannot be converted to jsonarray
```

I am not too sure where I am going wrong

when I toast the values of results its shows:

```
Santi Carzola Alex Chamberlin Theo Walcott ["Santi Carzola","Alex Chamberlin","Theo Walcott"]
```

Comment: Could you print the content of `result` just before this line : `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);` ?

Comment: Yes I can (when I check the values in results I can see the values) its just when it coverts it, it has a issue

Comment: Ok, but could you add it to your post above so we can see its content ?

Comment: I have edited the post, not sure if thats what its meant to contain

Comment: One of the problems is that you have `Santi Carzola Alex Chamberlin Theo Walcott ` before the `[` character, so for Android it's not a JSONArray but a String

Comment: how can I alter the response?

Comment: Try removing `echo $players[$i];` in your php code

Comment: No problem! I added it as an asnwer so you can accept it and close the subject!

Answer (score 0):

In your php code, you print each name once in the `while` loop :

```
echo $players[$i];
```

Then you print it again when you print the json array :

```
print(json_encode($players));
```

So in the `result`, you have the following :

```
Santi Carzola Alex Chamberlin Theo Walcott ["Santi Carzola","Alex Chamberlin","Theo Walcott"]
```

Which is not an `JSONArray`. You need to get rid of what is before the `[`, so remove the `echo $players[$i];` from your loop and it should work.